# Postgresql ISOYEAR first date

Tags: postgresql, date

How to get the start date of ISOYEAR in postgresql?

For example, i have a date 2012-01-01, isoyear is 2011 and it isoyear starts at 2011-01-03 and ends at 2012-01-01.

There is different ways to get isoyear, but i have no idea how to get date that iso year begins.

```
select extract(isoyear from '01.01.2012'::date) 

select to_char('01.01.2012'::date,'IYYY')
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? "Each ISO 8601 week-numbering year begins with the Monday of the week containing the 4th of January, so in early January or late December the ISO year may be different from the Gregorian year. See the week field for more information.

This field is not available in PostgreSQL releases prior to 8.3." Ref https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask it to convert the first "ISO day" of the "ISO year":

```
=> SELECT to_date('2011-0001', 'IYYY-IDDD');
  to_date
------------
 2011-01-03
```

Comment: Just an FYI: The formatting field is called `IDDD` (four characters) but you only need three digits; postgres docs say it takes values from `001` to `366`. Nice solution, though!